# Xamarin forms - Cannot access a disposed object error when using Master Detail navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a login page in Xamarin forms.

After logging in, I display a Master Detail page.
The detail page has a button that pushes another navigation page.
If I go to this page, and navigate back a few times, and log out, the next time I log back in, I get the error:

Cannot access a disposed object

If I simply pop the page, without navigating back, and I log out and log back in, this does not happen.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show some code. Your question is also a little confusing. You say you pop the page without navigating back. But when you pop a page, this is a back navigation. What are you exactly doing here?

Answer (score 0):

This was actually answered by someone else on SO. All I had to do was make sure I wasn't pushing a new Navigation page each time. If the page already existed, I just had to reuse it, and create a new nav page if it was null.